# How to prove that $f(z) := \bar{z}$, for $z \in \mathbb{C}$, is bounded on a rectangle $\mathcal{R} \subseteq \mathbb{C}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, functions, solution-verification, compactness

Let $f(z):=\bar{z}$, for $z=x+iy \in \mathbb{C}$. Explain why $f(z)$ is bounded on the rectangle $$\mathcal{R} := [a,b] + i[c,d] = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : a \leq \operatorname{Re}(z) \leq b , \hspace{0.2em} c \leq \operatorname{Im}(z) \leq d \}$$ with $a<b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $c<d \in \mathbb{R}$.

My attempt:

I proved this using the definition of a bounded function, i.e., if $f(z)$ is bounded, then there exists $M \geq 0$ such that $$M := \sup_{z \in U} \lvert f(z) \rvert < \infty$$ for $U \subseteq \mathbb{C}$.

In this case, I showed that
\begin{align*} M &= \sup_{z \in \mathcal{R}} \lvert f(z) \rvert = \sup_{z \in \mathcal{R}} \lvert \bar{z}^{2} \rvert = \sup_{x \in [a,b], \\ y \in [c,d]} \lvert x-iy \rvert^{2} \leq \\ &\leq \sup_{x \in [a,b], \\ y \in [c,d]} \lvert x+iy \rvert^{2} = \sup_{z \in \mathcal{R}} \lvert \operatorname{Re}(z) + i\operatorname{Im}(z) \rvert^{2} \\ &= \lvert b +id \rvert^{2} < \infty.\end{align*}
Therefore, $f(z)$ is bounded on $\mathcal{R}$. However, I'm not sure what kind of explanation (without proof) I can give to justify my calculations.

Since $f(z)$ is continuous and defined for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$, and $\mathcal{R}$ is closed (and therefore bounded), can I say that $f(\mathcal{R})$ is compact? and by saying this, would it be enough to justify the fact that $f(z)$ is bounded?

Comment: Are you asking why $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ is bounded when $x,y$ are bounded?

Comment: @copper.hat Not really, I think I might have worded the question wrong. The last two paragraphs I wrote are what I'm really asking (The proof I wrote above was kind of unnecessary). What I'm wondering is whether it's enough to say that since $\mathcal{R}$ is sequentially compact, and $f(z)$ is continuous $\forall z \in \mathbb{C}$, then $f(\mathcal{R}) := \{ f(z) : z \in \mathcal{R} \}$ is compact too. Thus, $f(z)$ is bounded[?].

Answer (score 1):

Without loss of generality, take $|a|<|b|$ and $|c| <|d|$.

Now $|f(z)|^2 = |z|^2 \le b^2 + d^2$ is bounded on the rectangle.